# How to Encrypt/Decrypt text in a file in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, keytool

I have a problem with my code, when I encrypt data, for example, in this case, the simmetric key I encrypted with the receiver's public key, then saved to a text file, when I read that text file and try to decrypt it, using the receiver's private key, I get a different key, therefore I cannot use it to decrypt the encrypted message.

Sender's code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

class Sender{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //infile.txt
        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        //outfile.txt
        File outFile = new File(args[1]);
        //mykeystore.jks
        File keyStoreFile = new File(args[2]);
        //mykeystore info
        String alias = args[3];
        String password = args[4];
        String storepass = args[5];
        //receptor certificate
        String receptorCert = args[6];

        try {
            //Read plain text
            FileInputStream rawDataFromFile = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            byte[] plainText = new byte[(int) inFile.length()];
            rawDataFromFile.read(plainText);

            //Create simmetric key
            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
            String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            //Encrypt plaintext
            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText);

            //Hash plaintext
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(plainText);
            byte[] digest = md.digest();

            //Encrypt simmetric key with receiver's public key          
            Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            PublicKey receptorPublicKey = getPublicKeyFromCert(receptorCert);
            rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, receptorPublicKey);
            byte[] simmetricKey = rsaCipher.doFinal(skeySpec.getEncoded());

            //Encrypt hash with my private key
            KeyStore myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
            myKeyStore.load(inStream, storepass.toCharArray());
            PrivateKey privatekey = (PrivateKey) myKeyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privatekey);            
            byte[] encodedHash = rsaCipher.doFinal(digest);

            //Write to outputfile
            FileOutputStream outToFile = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            outToFile.write(simmetricKey);
            outToFile.write(encodedHash);
            outToFile.write(ciphertext);

            outToFile.close();
            rawDataFromFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromCert(String certLocation) {
        PublicKey pub = null;
        try {
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(certLocation);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
            inStream.close();
            pub = (PublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pub;
    }
}
```

Receiver's code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Receiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Sender's out file
        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        //receiver's keystore
        File keyStoreFile = new File(args[1]);
        //receiver's keystore info
        String password = args[2];
        String alias = args[3];
        String storepass = args[4];
        //sender's cetificate
        File cert = new File(args[5]);

        try {
            //get Sender's out file
            FileInputStream rawDataFromFile = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            byte[] simmetricKey = new byte[256];
            byte[] hash = new byte[256];
            byte[] message;

            rawDataFromFile.read(simmetricKey);
            rawDataFromFile.read(hash);

            int b = rawDataFromFile.available();
            message = new byte[b];

            rawDataFromFile.read(message);
            //decrypt the simmetric key with receiver's private key
            KeyStore myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
            myKeyStore.load(inStream, storepass.toCharArray());
            PrivateKey privatekey = (PrivateKey) myKeyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            //
            Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            deCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);

            byte[] key = deCipher.doFinal(simmetricKey);

            System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(key));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error del sistema " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Now I can decrypt the simmetric key using the receiver's private key. But I dont know how to create a decoder using the same argument when I encrypted the message.

Sender's code to encrypt plain text.

```
    String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
    String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(iv.getIV());
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
```

Receiver's decryption 1

```
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKeySpec, "AES");
    Cipher decoder = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    decoder.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec);
    byte[] original = descipher.doFinal(message);
```

> ERROR: Given final block not properly padded

Receiver's decryption 2

```
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKeySpec, "AES");
    Cipher decoder = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    decoder.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec);
    byte[] original = descipher.doFinal(message);
```

> ERROR: Parameters missing

**FINAL UPDATE:**
Now my code works, thanks for all the help.
This code can be downloaded from here (btw, it's in spanish, but i don't think it matters):

[download](https://github.com/OmitsuDemon/cryptography)

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to use the `iv` in `decoder.init()`?

Comment: But, the iv wasn't for generate a new cipher? i just want to instantiate a cipher with the simmetric key. I've been testing with the IV but i obtain a different text from the original

Comment: Ok i got it, i was not receiving a different text, it was the text i wanted but it was Base64, so, the only thing i had to do was convert it to String like this: new String(myBase64), I will update the code here so people can get it.

Comment: @SebastianTareB. download link is broken, can you please update your final solution. thanks much.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is you are using AES to encrypt

> SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "**AES**");
>               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("**AES**/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

whereas to decipher,
you are using RSA,

> Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("**RSA**/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

Code snippet to use for encrypt/decrypt using AES

```
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class EncryptionDecryptionAES {
    static Cipher cipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        String plainText = "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption";
        System.out.println("Plain Text Before Encryption: " + plainText);

        String encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);

        String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text After Decryption: " + decryptedText);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, SecretKey secretKey)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey)
            throws Exception {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

Please check http://javapapers.com/java/java-symmetric-aes-encryption-decryption-using-jce/

Comment: Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if it helped to solve the problem.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: But he is using `Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` to encrypt the symmetric key with `byte[] simmetricKey = rsaCipher.doFinal(skeySpec.getEncoded());`

Comment: I use AES key to encrypt the message, but i use RSA public key to encrypt the AES key, then i try to decrypt the AES key using the RSA private key.

Comment: @OmitsuDæmon In your receiver program, you forget to use AES decryption.You directly used RSA algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your receiver tries to read **256 byte** for the encrypted symmetric key, but I think the RSA encrypted key only is **128 byte** long.

So maybe it works using

```
byte[] simmetricKey = new byte[128];
```

Comment: My simmetricKey is made with a 16 byte String(the key String(128 bit)), but the encrypted simmetricKey is 256 byte long. The skeySpec is 16 byte long. I've made some test inside the Sender class and all works well, but when i try to send the data through a text file, the problems begin.

Comment: I was just trying your code and I get an encrypted key with length 128 bytes... did you print out the length before saving it? And did you try to print out the encrypted key's bytes and compare that to the bytes in the file using a hex editor?

Comment: Nope, i just printed the results of the decryption of the key and compare it with the original

Comment: And what was the result? What kind of certificates are you using?

Comment: I'm using normal keytool generated certificates and keystore (2048). But now i think it's solved because i can decrypt the key and it's the same generated in the sender class.

But now i have another problem. I have to create a Cipher to decrypt using the simmetric key i decrypted. The cipher instance i use to encrypt is "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING" but i can't decrypt using the same because an error "Parameters missing", and when i try to use just "AES" it says "Given final block not properly padded"