# Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, utf-8, data-security

I have a client/server application that encrypts or decrypts a message both on the client-side and server-side. However on decryption I keep getting the following error from the StackTrace

> Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Following is the code from both the Server and Client classes.
The thing is I have tried using **("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")** and **("UTF-8")** but still haven't been able to fix said issue.
Any help would be appreciated thanks?

```
public class ServerApp   {

    public static byte[] encrypt(String input, Key k) {
        try {

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
            byte[] data = input.getBytes();
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);

            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipher, Key k) {
        try {

            Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
            byte[] original = cipher1.doFinal(cipher);
            return new String(original);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
            //Logger.getLogger(DES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        try {

              Key key=KeyGen.getSecretKey();
            ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(3333);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            Socket client = ser.accept();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           // SecretSocket sc = new SecretSocket(client, KeyGen.getSecretKey());
            String serMsg, cliMsg, plain;
           // OutputStream sout = sc.getOutputStream();
          //  InputStream sin = sc.getInputStream();
            do {
                System.out.print("You say: ");
                serMsg = scan.nextLine();

             //   sout.write(serMsg.getBytes());
            //    System.out.println("cli server "+sin.read());

                byte[] ci = encrypt(serMsg, KeyGen.getSecretKey());
            System.out.println("encrypt " +ci.toString());
             out.writeUTF(ci.toString());
              plain = decrypt(ci, KeyGen.getSecretKey() );
              System.out.println("decrypt " + plain);
            } while (!serMsg.equals("end"));
            client.close();
            ser.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ClientApp  {

        public static byte[] encrypt(String input, Key k) {
        try {

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
            byte[] data = input.getBytes();
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);

            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipher, Key k) {
        try {

            Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
            byte[] original = cipher1.doFinal(cipher);
            return new String(original);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
            //Logger.getLogger(DES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String serMsg, cliMsg, plain;

            do {

                System.out.println("server server "+in.readUTF());

                serMsg = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("enc: " + serMsg);
                plain = decrypt(serMsg.getBytes("UTF-8"), KeyGen.getSecretKey());
                System.out.println("Server says: " + plain);

            } while (!serMsg.equals("end"));
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] data = input.getBytes();
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

1. Using `DES` without IV you are implicitly using `DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`.
2. do not print a byte array directly. Java will output only printable characters. **Always encode and decode a byte array when printing (Hex or Base64 are the most common encodings)**

Here is an [example project](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/)

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray)
```

3. I hope you are aware DES is considered a weak cipher today and should be used only for backward compatibility.

Comment: Hey @RaghadMadwar I also wanted to bring to your attention that the solution in the answer above worked for me only when I was doing the encrypting. But I still got a **BadPaddingException** when trying to decrypt. However, after a few DuckDuckGo searches I came across this StackOverflow answer:- (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121787/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-text-in-a-file-in-java) by the user Naruto which seemed to fix the raised exception.

Comment: `/*Encryption inside a try block of course*/  SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish"); Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sks);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
String encryptedText = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted));`

Comment: `/*Decryption within  a try block as well*/ SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),"Blowfish"); Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks); Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder(); byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText)); String decryptedText = new String(decrypted);`